# ASP.NET MVC 2: foreach, RenderPartial, ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, viewdata, renderpartial

I'm trying to employ a technique that I came across that seems quite clean.

Previously, my Partial had the loop inside of it. I was looping through the mode within the Partial... but then I came across an example where the `foreach` loop existed in the main page, while the partial was just the meat of the loop.

They accomplished it like so:

```
<% int index = 1; // iteration
foreach (var item in Model.Deal) { %>

     <% Html.RenderPartial("DealList", item, new ViewDataDictionary {{ "index", index }}); %>

<% i++; // increase the interation
} %>
```

But in my example, I'm using a ViewModel, and now that I'm in the partial, I can't access "item" like I used to be able to. Instead my only option is `Model.Deal` ...

What is the point of passsing "item" with the `RenderParial` helper if I can't access it by saying `item.StoreName`? Note, both the View and the Partial are strongly typed to the same ViewDataModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the partial "DealList" your model will be whatever `item` is in the main view. Inside of the partial view, `Model.Deal` refers to a `Deal` object inside of `item` (from the main view).

This means that your `StoreName` property will be accessible as `Model.StoreName` within your partial view.

As a side note, I put together an extension method to deal with rendering of multiple partial views so as to not require the looping.

The new method is called `RenderPartials`:

```
public static void RenderPartials(this HtmlHelper helper, string partialViewName, IEnumerable models, string htmlFormat)
        {
            foreach (var view in models.Select(model =&gt; helper.Partial(partialViewName,model)))
            {
                helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Output.Write(htmlFormat, view.ToHtmlString());
            }
        }
```

Using this method you can simple say:

```
<% Html.RenderPartials("DealList",Model.Deal); %>
```

inside your main view, without the loop.

There's some more [information about this here](http://www.jamie-dixon.co.uk/mvc/rendering-a-partial-view-n-number-of-times-with-asp-net-mvc/) which explains more about the htmlFormat parameter etc.

Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: Well, that's what I though the logic would be... but when using `Model.`, I just get "Deal" in the intellisense and none of the following parameters... it's as if I'm doing `Model.Deal[i].StoreName` ... should my Partial be strongly typed to the same ViewModel or something else?

Comment: Your partial view should be strongly typed and accept a type that's the same as item. What is Deal a collection of?

Comment: My main view is strongly styped to `BLL.ViewModels.DealViewModel`, which contains "Deal" ... should that also be what my Partial is strongly typed to? Or just `<Deal>`?

Comment: Your partial view should be strongly typed to whatever "item" is in your loop. For example, lets say Model.Deal is an IEnumerable<DealItem>, which makes 'item' a 'DealItem', then your partial view should be strongly typed to the type 'DealItem'.

Comment: It's List. So if I calling `RenderPartial("DealList", item);`, my Partial should be strongly typed to `<List<Deal>>`?

Comment: If you're looping through a 'List<Deal>' then your partial should be strongly typed to type 'Deal' since that's what each item in your loop will be (that you're passing to your partial).

Comment: Technically, what I'm looping through was generated by a DBML, which resides in the BLL... a layer that the main peoject can't (and shouldn't be accessing). Hence the DealViewModel.

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference. If your looping through any collection, the type of 'item' will always be a single item from that collection, the equivelent of Model.Deal[i] in a standard (non foreach) loop.

Comment: So, just to clarify: my main view is strongly styped to `<BLL.ViewModels.DealViewModel>` and there is a `foreach` loop that looks like `foreach (var item in Model.Deal)` ... within that loop I am using `RenderPartial("DealList", item);` ... then, the Partial is strongly typed like this: `<Deal>`?

Comment: Assuming that Model.Deal in your loop is a collection of Deal objects, yes. Then you'll be passing a Deal object to the partial with each itteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>

@foreach (dynamic m in Model)
{
     @Html.Partial(MVC.Lists.Messages.Views._SingleMessage, (object)m)
}
```

Comment: You may want to explain your answer a little more... :)